# Is there a way to allocate more memory to GPU for the GPU Compute

Tags: rendering, gpu, optimization, opencl

I have been working on a solution to a situation I currently have with rendering using the GPU. In the process, I find that my Card's GPU Memory is only 512MB

First Question, Could this be why when I attempt to render and the kernels start to load, that it just sits on the blank render screen then eventually crashes the computer?

Second question, Is there a way to allocate more memory to the GPU maybe from the internal RAM? Or do I need to get a GC With more memory? I do have another AMD with, I think, More memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computer already do this automatically. VRAM is only storing very frequently-used resources that need to be accessed in a very short amount of time. If/when the VRAM is used up, most computers will attempt to transfer some of the less important information your your RAM.

DirectX, AGP and PCI-Express cards do this automatically.

You could manually assign more RAM to be used exclusively by your GPU, but this requires a lot of internal knowledge about computers and you have to know **exactly** what you're doing, because you can really mess up your computer this way. I won't add links to any tools that can do this, because there are always people stupid enough to attempt this without proper knowledge (Not saying you are, but there are bound to be someone in the future at least).

If you really want to do this manually, research it until you can feel comfortable messing with the RAM, an find the tools yourself. I don't want to be responsible for you frying your RAM cards.

If you do not have the proper knowledge about how to do this (which very few computer users do), you're better off inserting/buying a new GPU with more VRAM.

If you're on a laptop, chances are that your internal GPU uses some of your RAM if it runs out of VRAM. If this is the case, you should upgrade your laptop's RAM capacity.

**Final note**

RAM is **a lot slower** than VRAM, so you'll notice some real slowdowns in the rendering times. Also, again, do not attempt manually assigning RAM to your GPU without proper knowledge about this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It absolutely helps :D Thank you for the answer. I do know a little about that kinds of stuff, I do think a little research would be in order however, But I know enough that I could keep up with tutorials or how to's. I really do appreciate you keeping those things in mind and not posting those types of things : :D tells me that you are considerate towards others...A trait not so often seen these days.

Comment: All I needed really was just what you gave me. More of a validation that it could be done.

Comment: Glad the information helped you, and it's good to see people who understand the decision to not post links to software that can potentially cause damage. Hope you get something fixed to avoid the crashes.

Comment: I think I do, I gutted a few other computers, one I think was custom and set up for gaming, It has a sweet graphics card. I am more than sure will work beautifully. Thank you so much again :D